# Date Sort not working on datatables.net

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to sort a [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) table by `date` but it is not sorting correctly.

How can I sort by dates?

Comment: Share code samples it would be helpful to understand the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the aoColumns option

e.g.

```
"aoColumns": [{ "sType": "date" }]
```

Comment: Didn't work, killed my datatable

Answer (score 0):

I had used like this :-
 assign bSorting  as true For enabling datatable as sortable.

```
myGrid.dataTable({  'bSorting': true  });
```

then for each column i have assigned bSortable as true

```
'aoColumns': [
                 { 'bSortable': true, 'bSearchable': true},
                   { 'bSortable': true, 'bSearchable': false}  ]
```

Sample code :

```
myGrid.dataTable({'bSorting': true,'aoColumns':['sTitle': 'Person Name', 'bSortable':true]});
```